# Backbone.js unique attribute name across all models in collection for permalink

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I would like to make sure that a specific attribute is unique across the collection when a new model is created so that I can ultimately use this attribute as a permalink.

I have a List Collection and List Model. (CoffeeScript)

```
class App.Models.List extends Backbone.Model
  defaults:
    name: "My New List"

class App.Collections.ListSet extends Backbone.Model
  model: App.Models.List
```

When a new model is added to the ListSet, I would like to add a auto-incrementing number to the end of the name attribute if a model exists with that name already. For example `My New List 1` if a model existed with `My New List`.

I don't want it to be obtrusive and show an error, but just fix the problem automatically. I am happy with the logic behind adding the incrementing integer, but I need direction on where to put the code to make the changes.

Comment: Perhaps (appending) the model's `cid` might stand in for your uses? http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-cid

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get uniqueness until you talk to your server. Unless you only want uniqueness per-user and you want to assume that a user will only be using one instance of your application at a time.

Comment: Yeah I only want uniqueness per each users set of lists. Assume for the time being that there was only one instance of the app, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
App.Models.List = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(attrs) {
        this.set(attrs);
        this.set({originalName: attrs.name});

        var count = yourCollection.reduce(function(count,model){
            return count + (model.get('originalName') === this.get('originalName') ? 1 : 0);
        },0,this);

        if(count > 0) {
            this.set({name: this.get('name') + ' ' + count});
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a demo: [**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/446hV/3/)

What this should do is every time you initialize a model, you scan your collection to see if any other models have that same `originalName`. If so, you tack on the result to the name attribute.

**=== UPDATE ===**

I realize now that it's probably better to do the modification when the model is added to the collection, so as to decouple the model from the collection. Here's an updated code snippet:

```
App.Models.List = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(attrs) {
        this.set({originalName: attrs.name});
    }
});

App.Collections.Lists = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.List,
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('add',this.resolveNameConflict,this);
    },
    resolveNameConflict: function(model){
        var count = this.reduce(function(c,m){
            return c + (m.get('originalName') === model.get('originalName') ? 1 : 0);
        },0);
        if(count > 1) {
            model.set({name: model.get('originalName') + ' ' + (count-1)});
        }
    }
});
```

and a demo: [**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/446hV/5/)

Comment: And now I learned a good way to use the reduce function. I'm in favor of this answer. :-) The only caveat to this answer is if I add model with name listName_2 and the list already has two list items with the originalName, this model name will change to listName_3. Come to think of it, I think these solutions MUST assume that one has the entire collection at start.

Comment: @orangewarp The `originalName` attribute is set equal to the `name` attribute when the model is created. If you manually set the `name` to be "listName 2", then it will not change if there already exists 2 other models with an `originalName` of "listName". The real caveat to this solution is that if you create a new model with the name "ListName 2", it will not check to see if a model already exists which had its `name` changed to "ListName 2" by the `resolveNameConflict` function.

Comment: Ah. I neglected to really read the model code! :-P This solution would still require all models of the collection to be in place at start right? If I have 4 models in the DB but the way my app is set up I can add them individually - let's say I add 3... then if I add a new model it won't know about listName_4 and now we have two models with the same name. So maybe this is caveat number two.

Comment: @orangewarp I'm not sure I follow. My answer assumes you're not manually creating models with IDs suffixed to their names. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/446hV/7/ I'm creating models at run-time and adding them to the collection. The output shows that the names are correctly adjusted, while the original names remain intact

Comment: sorry for confusion. Yes. It works if we always start with an empty collection and create/add NEW models. It also works if we have a reset/fetch ALL existing models before creating new models. What I'm saying (maybe unimportant) is that if we're building these collections by picking and choosing existing models, it could fall apart. Using your example lets say I make a new collection and add the persisted models with modName Jack and Jack 1. Then I create a new model with origName Jack. The modName will become Jack 2. Conflict with the model that has been persisted to the server.

Comment: Depending on what purpose and how the asker plans on using these collections and models - it could make or break. If a model names are permalinks, I imagined these collections are for the purpose of mixing and matching these permalink lists on the fly. Some with new models and others with old persisted ones. So I'm not sure the collection guarantees all Jack models will be present for any new models to be given a unique modified name with the latest counter. To summarize though, I think your answer is good - it's the context I guess that I'm interested in hearing more about. Make sense?

Comment: Well, yes. A collection should only act on the models within that particular collection. If you want your `name` attribute to be unique across ALL records in your database, then it would make sense to have ALL your records in a Backbone collection. The only other way to do it would be to query the server every time a new model is create, which seems inefficient when you could have all that data on the client side; this is the point of Backbone.

Comment: (Nod) Mm. Thanks for taking your time with this discussion. It was helpful for me in terms of thinking about Backbone-y things.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: jackwander's answer is a better solution...**
I'm going to keep this here though because it's interesting to compare and contrast my naive solution to his. Beginner programmers, you can learn something by evaluating the two. :-)

---

I'll take a stab at it. You might do something like this. Basically we add an eventListener that does a name check every time you add a model to the collection. The `nameTracking` array is a sort of catalogue of name objects that have a unique name fragment and the counter which keeps track of what the last count of the name root is. Useful for our incrementing application.

```
ListSet = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.nameTracking = [];
        this.on('add', this.pushModelName, this);
    },

    pushModelName: function(model, collection) {

        // First, look through current collection for a model with same name
        var duplicate = this.find(function(listModel) {
            return model.get('name') === listModel.get('name');
        });

        // If duplicate exists, we lookup the name and counter in the nameTracking array.
        if (duplicate) {

            var nameObj = _.find(this.nameTracking, function(nameObj) {
                return nameObj.name === model.get('name');
            });

            // We increment the counter so that our added model is appended with the
            // correct, "latest" increment/indicator
            nameObj.count = nameObj.count++;
            model.set('name', model.get('name') + '_' + nameObj.count);

        // Otherwise it doesn't exist so we push the name into our nameTracking array
        } else {    // Not a duplicate, new name

            var modelName = model.get('name');

            this.nameTracking.push({
                'name': modelName,
                'count': 0
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Thing to note is that this assumes the model you're adding is a new model and not one that already has an id of a model that already exists in collection (not a clone.) You'd also want some way to update the `nameTracking[]` on collection initialization or `fetch()` because this assumes you're starting from scratch. I don't deal with removal of models and updating the name counter stuff but based on this sketch it shouldn't be hard to implement if you desire something of that nature.